# Why I'm getting different values than the simulator in precision half-wave rectifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier, precision-rectifier, half-bridge

I've build this circuit on the breadboard and with 5V AC I'm getting 2.5V at the output:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpDZYb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The problem is in the simulator it outputs 1.678V, which calculates to:

```
(1.678 x 2) / 0.636 = 5.27V
```

[Link to the simulator.](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BOJyWoSAHA2BmBA2HMBAdgCYzIccAWEEiCAVkhCYFMBaMMAKAEMQZGq2JkQOJuLGZwTEN3lh48KLBU0wZfFRI0RkTSSZ1RKyLwDuQkeBL4boshii8AJhKngE4ydOdCIG7sAGb8AK4ANgAuVkKQLmD2jnYOFgBO8YnJWtlp4CpxlHlZQkxpRQllDn7Vrh61ZOWe0j6BwWFRsZnCTi61uVAF8LwASuABSQ4EqUPMrPKsS9BMvADmKcWbwkMWAPItEy6aDoNLvJTotRisvZhLauZoz8jgKwiQJDjCZF80ehgIDA4IwirYbikznFrqwBgELAB7EDofCmEAiBCJZYqUj4cpNIbiK68JE8ECouYUD5vfAkG4sfRkAiQJgYHCPEHgcC8IA)

Why the results are different?

Comment: Measure the resistance of \$R_1\$ on the breadboard. The simulation shows an output of 2.473V if its value is 15k instead of 10k.

Comment: @uriyabsc Both resistors are ~10K.

Comment: Recheck the connections on the breadboard. It might be easier if you simplify the schematic first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The problem is in the simulator it outputs 1.678V, which calculates
> to: (1.678 x 2) / 0.636 = 5.27V*

The theoretical **average** value of a ½ wave rectified signal is the **peak** voltage (5 volts) divided by \$\pi\$. So you should get 1.59 volts at the mid point of the ripple on your falsetad simulation. **And it looks like you do**.

The peak of 1.678 is the wrong place to look because it is meaningless in the context of rectification and smoothing <-- it's the mid-point average of the ripple voltage where you look. If the simulation didn't auto-scale (very annoying) it would be easier for you to see.

So, if your real circuit output is 2.5 volts you might be making the same mistake and looking at the peak ripple voltage when the capacitor value you have used is significantly less than 10 uF.

Comment: Found the problem; It needed a 10K as a load at the Vout to output proper value.

Comment: You might be swallowing a spider to catch a fly.

Comment: Adding/removing a capacitor don't have an effect on the output voltage, neighter increasing or decreasing the value of it. the only thing that happens to be the problem is that output is not loaded. so where's the fly.

Comment: BTW how can I not look at the peak value when the capacitor only stores the peak value?

Comment: Where you have your capacitor (across the 10 k resistor in the feedback loop, it will average the rectified signal. If you want the peak value then the capacitor need to be from the output to 0 volts @ElectronSurf (this might be the fly)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, the cap, resistor, input voltage peak and frequency are determining the peak voltage here. Since you confirm that resistor value is correct on bench (I hope you confirmed this by using a multimeter). Then, either frequency is less than 50Hz on bench or cap used is less than 10uF on bench.

Use an oscilloscope and confirm that the input waveform is as expected and use a multimeter to check the cap value.